# What tool can I use to block light from a 50W bulb?

Tags: lighting

I bought a lamp & the incandescent bulb is not fully covered by the shade. Since the shade is at eye level that hurts my eyes. What can I use safely to block the light?  Any tape safe to use? Or does anything exist for such an issue?

I'm using 2 50W olden type incandescent bulbs with the lamp.

Lamp I got:

https://www.wayfair.ca/lighting/pdp/brayden-studio-davey-61-led-tree-floor-lamp-bstu5008.html?piid%5B0%5D=26194658&piid%5B1%5D=26194659

Answer (score 1):

Photographers use Cinefoil to block light. They attach these foils to the barn doors of lights with pegs. You could try to clamp such foil to the shade, but make sure the peg itself is heat resistance. Don't fully cover/wrap the bulb/shade with foil. Bulbs can get extremly hot after some time. The heat of the bulb should have enough space to exit.

Examples of Cinefoil:

- https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00915LB6M/ref=oh_aui_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1
- https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/44690-REG/Rosco_RS100113_Matte_Black_Cinefoil.html
- https://static1.squarespace.com/static/50aa7079e4b040d142112688/t/576c2863893fc0c13dd81ad0/1466706022795/ (Cinefoil attached to barn door)

Downside: They are quiet pricey. Therefore a new shade might be cheaper.

Comment: How much heat can the Cinefoil take? Can it burn if I tape it on the shade?

Comment: Not sure about that. I use Cinefoil to block light of a 800W bulb. The foil is approx. 10 cm away from the bulb. I keep plenty of space without foil to let the heat exit.

Comment: Damn it has to be 10cm away. So I can't just tape it over the shade? :-( How would I hang cinefoil randomly around a lamp?

Comment: Its 10 cm away from the bulb.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use a "half silvered" bulb in those fixtures.  These specialty bulbs are relatively common and are made for cases such as a light fixture hanging over a table where you don't want bright, direct light shining straight into people's eyes.  I've seen these sold at most hardware stores, but you may have to ask someone to help find them.

The silvered side is totally opaque and is designed to reflect the light towards the shade where it can be diffused.

[image: Half Silvered Bulb]

*Image from HomeDepot.com*

Comment: Never seen these but I wonder if they make them in incandescent. So far the only incandescent bulb I can find (now that most are banned ) are a 50W work bulb.I don't like LED or CFL. Damn, need E26 base though. Looks like these silvered ones are another type.

Comment: That example image was the first I found... I’ve never actually seen an LED model in person - only seen incandescent. This is an old style of bulb that predates LED and CFL.  I’ve seen them in a type A bulb and a globe bulb and I believe I’ve seen one with a candelabra base (E12), but most of the time it’s a standard (E26) base.

Comment: @Jhi1618's My lamp needs a E26/Medium (Standard) base but can I use other shaped bulbs in it besides the common A19?

Comment: The only thing that determines the shape of bulb is how tight the shade is around the socket.  From that picture it looks like most bulb shapes would fit.  Here is a [standard sized](https://www.amazon.com/Bulbrite-60A19HM-Half-Chrome-Shape/dp/B004YSVJTA/) incandescent, half silvered bulb.  You just need to look online or get to a hardware store - I'm sure you can easily find something that will work.

Comment: Thanks! I had emailed Bulbrite this morning asking where I can buy their bulb! I did assume the "incandescent" meant "led" or "halogen" as Sylvania uses the word incandescent but their bulbs aren't true incandescent  except for rough service as most are banned in Canada.

Comment: Interesting because incandescent literally means "emitting light as a result of being heated".  Maybe they use it in marketing to refer to the color of the light.  Early LEDs got a bad name for being to white and poor at color rendition (CRI).

Comment: Bulbrite brand seems to stop working or blows into pieces easily. Damn. Do you know any other brands that make silver topped bulbs? How are these different than silver topped ones: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/aw/d/B000GWKJZS/ref=ox_sc_saved_image_1?smid=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&psc=1

Comment: @verve Those look like the same thing except they are frosted rather than clear.  They say "half chromed", so they have the same silver reflective top on the inside.

Answer (score 1):

### Use an LED bulb that is physically shorter

LED bulbs come in many shapes and sizes. Look around for one that has the shape and light emission pattern you want.  For instance PAR style spotlight that is fairly squat may fill the bill.